# Opening mobile keyboard on button click

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, mobile, gatsby

On my webpage, I have a "register now" button in the header. On click this button will scroll the user to the bottom of the page and will, ideally, focus on a form field input and open the soft keyboard on mobile devices.

I am currently executing a .focus and .click state to the element after the smooth scroll function ends. While these two statuses are being applied, they are not opening the keyboard as desired.

```
    componentDidMount = () => {
        Events.scrollEvent.register('end', function(to, element) {
            if(element.id === 'request-demo'){

                var inputFocus = document.getElementById('name');

                inputFocus.focus(console.log("focused"));   
                inputFocus.click(console.log("clicked"));
            }
        Events.scrollEvent.remove('end');
        });
    }
```

This function will open the keyboard on Android devices, but not IOS.

I am avoiding jQuery for this project, so vanilla solutions would be preferred

Comment: Does it work if you remove the smooth scroll and trigger the focus immediately?

Comment: Have you tried a more react way of using a ref attached to the input to focus and scroll into view the input? AFAIK the native keyboard should (_mostly_) just work in the native browser. Is this just running in safari mobile or are you wrapped PWA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOS will not allow developers to simulate user inputs within react-scroll's scrollEvent. By removing the focus and click states from within the end of scroll event, we were able to resolve this issue

Our current interpretation is that IOS blocks developers from simulating user inputs within on event functions, however any further insight would still be greatly appreciated